Maven force clean (remove)
How can I tell Maven to remove dir/file forcefully? (I can manually delete it just fine, sometimes Maven works, sometimes not, seems 50/50)

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/form-src/node_modules</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


Try re-running maven with -X to see the full error. There could be a number of reasons why, a shot-in-the-dark guess being that the directory is locked/"in use" when the delete is attempted. Without the error, guessing is all we have.

Do you run this in MS Windows?

Why do you want to clean something in the src folder? Files should always be generated to the target folder.

@cyberbrain No, Eclipse on MacOS

@JFabianMeier Files are generated INTO the target folder (which is deleted on every "clean") but this is the src folder where I want to refetch node_modules every clean hence my question...

@Rogue I did run maven with -X, screenshot attached. Cannot delete library mrz in node_modules ...

@DavidDunham Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.. Also add the full output of the maven execution, you might have cut off the reason of the exception in the screenshot.

oh, it's node_modules - maybe a virus scanner is still working inside and prevents deletion? node_modules is known to struggle with background file operations since it contains so many tiny files. Are there any files left (check also for hidden ones) in the folder that could not be deleted?

it could also be other software that accesses files in that folder, e.g. an IDE that scans dependencies in node_modules
